# Структура скриптов: как на Питоне раскладывать скрипты по папкам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как на Питоне раскладывать скрипты по папкам. Допустим я пишу скрипт и хочу разложить файлы по разным папкам, например все что относится к юзерам, в папку `user`, все что к статьям - в папке `articles`.

Все что нашел в интернете, так это в главной скрипте добавить папку в системную переменную, в которой находится список путей, где Питон ищет модули.  Это получается что мне надо написать функцию, которая при каждом запуске скрипта просканирует всю папку проекта, соберет все папки которые в ней есть и всех их добавить в переменную окружения? Не скажется или это на производительности? Это же кошмар, нет?

Я сужу по PHP, так как в нем у меня побольше опыта. Там например есть autoload, который берет namespace, и если такого класса нет, то он берет namespace, заменяет слэши на противополжные и рассматривает его как путь до файла с классом и подключает его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автолоада нет. Все файлы должны импортироваться как модули. Если выносишь их в отдельную папку, то просто положи в эту папку пустой файл `__init__.py` и папка станет модулем для питона. В этот файл можно положить код который относится к корню этого модуля или импортировать в него нужные функции файлов-подмодулей.

```
main.py
|---foo
    |---__init__.py
    |---bar.py
```

### **init**.py

```
from bar import worker
```

### bar.py

```
def worker():
    pass
```

### main.py

```
# из подмодуля напрямую
import foo.bar
foo.bar.worker()

# через импорт внутри `__init__.py`
import foo
foo.worker()
```

На производительности кода это никак не сказывается даже в больших проектах. Но если файлов действительно много понадобится немного времени, чтоб прочитать эти все файлы с диска на старте скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего это работает не много по другому вам стоит начать с понимания ООП а так же модулей в питоне.

Что касается ответов на конкретные вопросы. Питон ищет модули относительно текущего выполняемого скрипта или из директории в которую сохраняются pip модули.
Вам не нужно иметь переменных окружения в данном контексте. 
Модули импортируются перед выполнением скрипта по этому на производительности это ни коим образом не скажется.
Если питон не найдет модуль среди соседних файлов (или папки если таковая указана) то он просто выкинет ошибку ImportError и скрипт завершится.